# Get the value of an Element in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

i'm trying to get the value of a Object in my array. Basically when i'm doing

```
var firsts = response.data;
console.log(firsts)
```

I have something like that

```
{
 "EUR_BND": 1.603476
}
```

But the name of the object is changing every time, so i can't do

```
response.data.EUR_BND
```

I wondered if there was a way to directly get the value of the only object, without having to go through its name.

Comment: `Object.keys(firsts).forEach((key) => console.log(key, firsts[key]));`? There's also `Object.entries()` and `Object.values()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the object.values

```
Object.values(response.data)
```

Which would return an array of the values in the object

`Object.values(response.data)[0]` would return the value if you have one

Answer (score 2):

You could retrieve the keys with

```
Object.keys(obj)
```

like it is stated in the docs and then access the value like you normally would:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 2):

Try best way to get all key and value in loop

```js
const data = {
 "EUR_BND": 1.603476,
 "TEST_BND": 3.4,
 "TEST2_BND": 5.6
}
    var key;

for (key in data) {
    console.log(key+' '+data[key])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Object.values`:

```js
const data = {
 "EUR_BND": 1.603476,
 "TEST_BND": 3.4,
 "TEST2_BND": 5.6
}

console.log(Object.values(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.values gives you a list of all values of a object keys, you can use it

```
<script>
data = {
 "EUR_BND": 1.603476
};
value_a = Object.values(data)[0];
console.log(value_a); #1.603476
</script>
```

This way you don't need to use the object key to get the value

Answer (score 0):

This is how you may access "EUR_BND" key within response.data or firsts object.

```
var firsts = response.data;
var keys = Object.keys(firsts);
console.log(firsts[keys[0]]);
```

I would suggest having a look at `Object.keys` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me, is to get the list of keys and then you can do whatever you want with it,
Maybe your need can evolve in the future, so it is recommended that you start by getting your keys and do the logic you wish

```
var keys = Object.keys(data);
if(keys && keys.length>0)
{
var firstValue = data[keys[0]];
//other staff
}
```